# Webstorm 8 trial - Live Edit doesn't work

Tags: webstorm

Looked up all posts according to live edit on the forum and the help desk at jetbrains, but i can't get Live Edit with Webstorm 8 trial to work.

1. Live edit plugin in webstorm enabled and activated (view)
2. Chrome Jetbrain ide installed
3. Jetbrain ide log says - System latest connected to WebStorm 8.0.4 (127.0.0.1:63342)
4. Use Webstorm 8 view -> open in browser, chrome (localhost:63342/myPage.html)

Already changed port in ide and webstorm settings to anyport, doesnt work.
May I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live edit only works in debug session context. Please see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Live+Edit

Note that recent recent Chrome API changes have made it incompatible with WebStorm debugger. So if your Chrome version is higher than 36.*, you need to upgrade to webstorm 8.0.5 to be able to debug/live edit your code